# characters extended ascii display PHP

Tags: php, encoding

I have a code that printing properly ascii character upto 127. But its not printing extended ascii characters properly.

```
$data = "Two Ts and one F.";
foreach (count_chars($data, 0) as $i => $val) {
   echo "There were $val instance(s) of " , chr($i) , " in the string.<br/>";
}
```

its output same from 128 to 255 is :

```
There were 0 instance(s) of � in the string.
```

I have saved my file in `utf-8 encoding`

Comment: check this link:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028449/why-is-this-the-extended-ascii-character-%C3%A2-%C3%A9-etc-getting-replaced-with-c

Comment: You have saved your file as UTF-8. What does that look like?

Comment: I think you want like this:-https://eval.in/925234

Comment: @Anant singh my question is more focused on encoding concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i got your point, you need to do like this:-

```
<?php

$data = "Two Ts and one F.";
foreach (count_chars($data, 0) as $i => $val) {
   echo "There were $val instance(s) of ". utf8_encode(chr($i)) ." in the string.".PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output:- https://eval.in/925240

Comment: its working but i have a question. why i need explicitly utf8_encode while i have already same my file in utf-8?

Comment: @Curious  i am unable to say untill i really check that your file is actually `utf-8` encoded or not already.