# PHP, HTML and character encodings

Tags: php, html, character-encoding

I actually have a fairly simple question but I'm unable to find an answer anywhere. The PHP function html_entity_decode is supposed to "converts all HTML entities to their applicable characters from *string*."

So, since `&#937;` is the HTML encoding for the Greek captical letter Omega, I'd expect that `echo html_entity_decode('&#937;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');` would output Ω. But instaid, it outputs some strange characters which my browser can't recongize. Why is this?

Thanks,

Martijn

Comment: What encoding is your output in? My guess is ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Hm, you're right. Now I've added `header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` to my file and I'm able to see the Omega sign. So stupid I didn't think about that before. A second problem I was dealing with, was that the source contained &amp;#937, so I had to run html_entity_decode twice: once for the &amp -> & conversion, second for the &#937 -> Omega-sign conversion. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you convert entities into UTF-8 characters like your last parameter specifies, your *output* encoding must be UTF-8 as well. Otherwise, in a single-byte encoding like ISO-8859-1, you will see double-byte characters as two broken single ones.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. Indeed, I saw two "strange" characters, but didn't know that was the reason.

Answer (score 1):

It's works fine:

http://codepad.viper-7.com/tb2LaW

Make sure your webpage encoding is UTF-8

If you have different encoding on webpage change this:

```
html_entity_decode('&#937;', ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
                                          ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
header('Content-type: text/html;charset=utf-8');

mysql_set_charset("utf8", $conn);
```

Refer this URL:-

http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/charsets

[php mysql character set: storing html of international content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681228/php-mysql-character-set-storing-html-of-international-content)

Comment: phpwact.org contains really useful information, thanks! What a great community is Stackoverflow..