# Pros / Cons storing mysql accent vs html-entities?

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php mysql character set: storing html of international content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681228/php-mysql-character-set-storing-html-of-international-content)

I am wondering should I store my accent (ë, é, è...) as HTML-ENTITIES such as `&euml;` or directly as it in my mysql database?

I plan to use it mostly to `echo` them with php or search it for through a php search engine.

What are the pros and cons?

Comment: I don't think there is a pros/cons of submitting accented letters characters

Comment: Please, please, please, as they are, not converted for HTML. What happens if you want to use them in a non-HTML context? And note, most characters don't need entities if you are using a character set that has them, utf-8 for instance.

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html + rule of thumb -> MySql DB + table `utf8_general_ci`, utf8 connection via the `SET NAMES utf8` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2159434/set-names-utf8-in-mysql) and meta charset header utf-8 and you go something going

Answer (score 0):

Store them in valid encoding with no convertation to HTML entities. Sorting and comparation will work well in database thanking to [Character Sets and Collations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-charsets.html).

It is always good practice to encode values in echo-time (post processing). But filtering (strip tags as an example) should be done before save (pre processing).